# Docker Compose "ERROR: file not found", but ubuntu shell can find the file

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm trying to get a Docker Compose script to test a python program. The following is the .sh to run the docker-compose command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script_path=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
base_path=${script_path}/src

container_path=${base_path}/deploy/
docker_compose_path=${container_path}docker-compose.yml

sudo nano ${base_path}/tests/scrap/test_r.py

docker-compose -f "${docker_compose_path}" run service_name pytest -x ${base_path}/tests/scrap/test_r.py
docker-compose -f "${docker_compose_path}" down
```

The problem when running it is that an error shows up with the following message:

```
ERROR: file not found: /correct/path/to/test_r.py
```

NOTE: I have checked many times and the path (absolute) is correct.

The odd thing about the error is that the shell can find it with no problem. The nano command that is right on top of the docker-compose one works perfectly, loading the file with the correct content. Still, with the same exact path, docker-compose seems to not be able to find it and execute it (already tried chmod +x test_r.py but it did not work. Docker Compose simply doesn't find it).

Whatever extra info that you need, you can ask. Thanks :P

NOTE: I'm not considering as a source of the problem the fact that the project worked perfectly on another computer that was running MacOS. My pc is trying to execute the scripts in an Ubuntu environment. If taking that into account is a step in the right direction, I don't know how to move toward solving the issue.

Edit: adding info of the file docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  service_name:
    image: image_name
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ../../../workers:/opt/workers/
    working_dir: /opt/workers/src
    env_file:
      - ../local/worker.env
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the contents of your `docker-compose.yml` file, at least the `service_name` service?  Containers frequently have different filesystem layouts from the host (it's very common for a packaged application to be in `/app`, independent of the host filesystem layout) so your absolute path may not work here.

Comment: Already updated the question. Sorry for the generic naming of services but I'm trying to keep confidentiality here...

Comment: Is `${base_path}` in your script the `workers` directory you mention in `volumes:`?

Comment: StackOverflow does not let me close the question for the next 22 hours, but I asked all of your questions to my boss and everything went alright. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was update the "working_dir" path in the docker-compose.yml file to make it find the corresponding py file. The problem was that I had no idea that I had to pay attention to that info. Thanks to @David Maze for asking me all of the questions. Sometimes asking the right ones points on in the right direction.